# Парсинг иконок приложений телефона

Tags: android, python, icon, android-manifest

Подскажите, как с помощью python спарсить иконки всех приложений на андроид?
Я так понимаю, они находятся в манифесте в корневой папке. Но я не смог никак его найти.
Есть ли какие-то способы без сторонних приложений *достучаться* до этих данных?

Comment: На Java такое делал в своем приложении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Манифест я так и не нашел, но смог получить иконку с помощью `google-play-scraper`.
Через него можно получить информацию о скаченном приложении, включая иконку.

https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/